# Python: Determining odd and even numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Having trouble with a part of a homework assignment. I'm not sure how to do what it's asking. The object of the assignment is to determine if a number is odd or even and then print one of the two statements. I know how if / else statements work, I just don't know how to figure out if a number is odd or even! (I know, I'm terrible). Any help would be appreciated. Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
user_num = 13
if #your solution goes here:
    print('Even')
else:
    print('Odd')
```

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask yourself: "*When is a number odd? What are the condition(s) that should be met?*"

Comment: so would it be like if the number is not divisible by 2? forgive me but I was always crap at math which is why I keep asking so many questions here, lol. Could I use modulus and divide by 2 because anything odd will always have a remainder?

Comment: `if user_num % 2 == 0`

Comment: Exactly. So what should your program do? Calculate the modulus of a division by two. And if it is not zero, then...

Comment: You must check if the number "user_num" is odd or even. To do this, read about these concepts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics))

Comment: Thanks Willem I was able to figure it out without you having to do everything for me which feels better. Haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any EVEN number divided by two is a whole number.

How would you go about determining this?
Is it easier to find if the number is a whole number or if dividing gives a remainder.

Say 5 divided by 2. This would be 2 with a remainder of 1.
Or with your number, 13 divided by 2 is 6 remainder 1.

Finding if something has a remainder of 1 is easier than checking if the answer leaves a whole number. How do you check if something has a whole number?

Think of discrete math here. When doing divisor operations. There is a specific term I am alluding to.

Comment: Thank you! Between you and Willem above I was able to write the formula correctly using %

Answer (score 0):

A number is called even if it is divisible by 2, i.e, the remainder should be 0. Using the modulo operator in Python you can get your answer.

So your code should go like this:

```
user_num=13
if(user_num%2==0)
    print('Even')
else
    print('Odd')
```